# JavaScriptInterface methods not recognizable (Android webview)

Tags: javascript, java, android, ajax, webview

I have in my MainActivity:

```
 webView.addJavascriptInterface( new JavaScriptInterface( this ), "ajaxHandler" );
....
 public class JavaScriptInterface
    {
        Context mContext;

        JavaScriptInterface( Context c ) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void DoSomething( String dataToPrint )
        {
          .....
        }
}
```

I read that the problem might be proguard.
So I updated the proguard rules file :

```
-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
     public *;
 }

-keep public class com.example.testapp.JavaScriptInterface
-keep public class * implements com.example.testapp.JavaScriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class * implements com.example.testapp.MainActivity.JavaScriptInterface{
    public *;
}
```

It didn't help though... in the chrome debugger, since I put in console the ajaxHandler object and the DoSomething method, I can see the ajaxHandler object as `Object {}`
 but it's empty, and the method DoSomething is `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interface class

```
public class JavaScriptInterface
    {
        Context mContext;

        JavaScriptInterface( Context c ) {
            mContext = c;
        }
        @JavascriptInterface //add this
        public void DoSomething( String dataToPrint )
        {
          .....
        }
}
```

In proGuard.pro file

```
-keep public class com.example.testapp.MainActivity$JavaScriptInterface
-keep public class * implements com.example.testapp.MainActivity$JavaScriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class * implements com.example.testapp.MainActivity$JavaScriptInterface{
     <methods>;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Use `$` sign not `.` to get inner interface class name.

Comment: thank you, the `@JavascriptInterface` annotation partially helped - I can see now the method in the chrome debugger, but it isn't being invoked in my app code for some reason.(the javascript code is good since I'm using the same javascript code on an iOS version of the app and it works there perfectly..)

Comment: have changed your proGuard.pro file

Comment: I can replace the `<methods>;` with `public *;` right? It still doesn't work though, I can see the method in the chrome debugger but it's not being called inside my app

Comment: interface name start with $

Comment: and also try #-keepattributes JavascriptInterface